# Are Windows Forms calls to Databases encrypted?

Tags: c#, datagridview

For example, if I populate a DataGridView from an SQL connection string, is the connection between the application and the database encrypted, or could a network sniffer see it?

Thanks,
CJ

Comment: pretty it is not encrypted... some one will post a complete answer with more knowledge

Comment: This depends :), from what you say, i can go to the assumption there a network call in the middle, if so, then it depends if the comunication is encrypted or not.

Comment: How would you make something that would *sniff* the network to look at such data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not encrypted by default but you can encrypt it using [Encrypted Connections](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2005/11/10/491563.aspx)

See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for more details

Comment: Thank You. That is what I was afraid of.

Answer (score 2):

Encryption is dependent on the database provider's capabilities and configuration.

C# does not participate in the over the wire protocol so in the general case, no, the database calls would not be encrypted.